# Ribbon button - Move selected items into Document Set

Tags: ribbon, document-set

How do I create a button on the ribbon and how do I move the selected item(s) from the list/library into a Document Set?

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? It seems like you're asking for a complete solution, rather than the answer to a specific query.

Comment: @StuartPegg I did some editing to save this question. I provided an answer as well :)

Comment: @VedranRasol: :) Fair enough. However, it seemed like they were asking how they could enable a ribbon button when a list item is selected (in the first part of their question).

Comment: @StuartPegg Thx, just to be on safe side I updated my answer to cover that option. I hope this question is now saved :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you have something quite similar (just few changes needed):

[How to Display a SharePoint Dialog from Ribbon Button and Get Selected Item Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfrost/archive/2009/11/08/how-to-display-a-sharepoint-dialog-from-ribbon-button-and-get-selected-item-context.aspx)

Basically you need two things:

1. Custom ribbon/button similar to one described in article. With usage of dialog framework you open custom page and pass selected items values as querystring (all described in provided article)
2. Custom Application page with one TextBox (DocumentSet name) and 2 buttons (OK, Cancel). OnLoad you read selected items from query string (article) and on button OK click you create your Document Set and move selected items into it (not in article!)

For that last part you can use info provided here: [How to programmatically create document set, add or move files, GetDocumentSetById](http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/12/programmatically-create-document-set.html)

For more info on Ribbon customizations I recommend reading [SharePoint 2010 Ribbon Customization series](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html) by Chris O'Brien (@ChrisOBrienMVP).

**Addition (thx goes to @StuartPegg):**

Some info on how to enable Ribbon Button when item(s) in list is(are) selected:

[Enable Ribbon button when one item only is selected and it is not folder](http://antoniolanaro.blogspot.com/2011/04/enable-ribbon-button-when-one-item-only.html)

[SharePoint 2010 Ribbon Customization Part VI: How to enable/disable buttons in ribbon conditionally?](http://makarandrkulkarni.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-customization_23.html)